# Why can't observable be posted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a select2 option in html.

**AddPermission.cshtml**

```
          <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Parent Permission:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="ParentPermission" name="ParentPermission" class="large m-wrap" data-bind='options: permissions, optionsText: "permissionName", optionsValue: "id", optionsCaption: "Seçiniz...", value: parentId, select2: { }'>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Permission Name:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="m-wrap large" type="text" id="PermissionName" name="PermissionName"
                        data-bind="value: permissionName" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button class="btn blue" data-bind="click: savePermission">
                    <i class="icon-ok"></i>Save</button>
            </div>
```

I have some observables in my knockout javascript file and one of these is parentId.

**PermissionModel.js**

```
  return function () {

        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable(0);
        self.permissionName = ko.observable("");
        self.parentId = ko.observable("");
        self.permissions = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.clearModel = function () {
            self.id(0);
            self.permissionName("");
            self.parentId("");
        }

        self.savePermission = function () {
            console.log(self.parentId() + self.permissionName());
            webRequest.postJSON("/Administration/Permission/AddPermission", ko.toJSON(self), self.savePermissionSucceeded);
        }

        self.getPermissions = function () {
        webRequest.postSingle("/Administration/Permission/GetAllPermissions", null, self.getPermissionsSucceeded);
    }
}
```

Before page loaded, I call **getPermissions** function to load my all permissions to select2 option menu. It works successfully. I call **getPermissionsSucceeded** function after **getPermission** as you can see,

**PermissionModel.js**

```
    self.getPermissionsSucceeded = function (result) {

    self.permissions.removeAll();
    var dataLength = result.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        var data = result[i];
        var permission = new PermissionSearchResultModel(data.Id, data.Name, data.ParentId)
        self.permissions.push(permission);
    }
```

**PermissionSearchResultModel.js**

```
function PermissionSearchResultModel(Id, PermissionName, ParentId) {
        var self = this;
        self.id = Id;
        console.log(self.id);
        self.permissionName = PermissionName;
        self.parentId = ParentId;
    }
```

Then I write a permission name and select a parent permission value from the list. They all must be posted to server from **savePermissions** function in knockout javascript file.

**PermissionController.cs**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddPermission(PermissionModel model)
        {
            Permission permission = PermissionService.AddPermission(model.Id, model.PermissionName, model.ParentId);

            if (permission.Id != 0)
            {
                return Json(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return new JsonNetResult() { Data = new { Error = true, Messages = new[] { new { Message = "Bu yetki önceden kayıt edilmiş." } } } };
            }

        }
```

**PermissionService.cs**

```
public static Permission AddPermission(int id, string permissionName, int parentId)
        {
            GenericRepository<Permission> permissionRepository = new GenericRepository<Permission>();
            Permission tempPermission = permissionRepository.First(d => d.Name == permissionName && d.ParentId == parentId);

            if (tempPermission == null)
            {
                tempPermission = new Permission();
                tempPermission.Name = permissionName;
                tempPermission.ParentId = parentId;
                permissionRepository.Add(tempPermission);
                return tempPermission;
            }

            return new Permission();
        }
```

When I checked the firebug I noticed that the parentId observable value can not be posted to server so a new record is added to db without parentId even it has a parentId value. Other observables can be posted.

Comment: Please cut the question down to the actual problem.

Comment: When I posted values to server, only permissionName and id can be sent, parentId value was undefined even it had a value. Actual problem is that.

Comment: you sure you getting `self.parentId` before saving . keep debugger in click function and check the value of it using quickwatch or alternately console.log it . most important thing viemodel & server model should be in sync . else you get no data in post for mismatch of model entities .

Comment: i solved the problem. i added some js librarires from anohter project and it was posted to server correctly. i don't know which library have might worked?